# Break the line if there is no space

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

If i am adding multiple text views in android it gets hide i need to break when screen finished
As an example my code is something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="last checking text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the result seems to be

[image: this is the screenshot]

I need the text to break down when screen finished down 
and break to another line. 
this is only the example code i am doing this thing programmatically, so please dont answer of adding more linear layout.

Comment: why do you need too much textview ?

Comment: change the orientation of Linear layout to vertical

Comment: i need it to be horizontal but when the screen gets finished i need it to break down and the next text view come underneath it

Comment: why not one `TextView` for that?

Comment: i am doing this programatically so i need multiple text views and they will perform different actions . the code i pasted was just an example

Comment: Instead of doing this , make single text view . All the sentence written in string and and set in that text view . It will automatically split after screen is finish.

Comment: Do you need number of textviews at run time, Like to display list of values

Comment: yes @JyotiJK need multiple textviews that will perform different actions. so i cannot do it one text view

Comment: that will perform different actions--> Can you explain it

Comment: @JyotiJK every textview will perform different set on click listener i am just having the problem of layout the layout is not breaking the line when line gets finished.

Comment: I will recommend you to use Gridview

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: @AdeelFaisal If you want to implement your approach and facing only layout issue then you can go with **FlexboxLayout**. Check my answer for reference.

Answer (score 3):

For flexible layout you can go with **FlexboxLayout** and details you can get from [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) and for [Open source FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) dependency you can reach to Github.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want your textView appearing with multiple line with a scrollable properties, then no need to use multiple textView.
```

Check the bellow solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"`enter code here`
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

And bellow code on your Activity:
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_id);
txtView.setText("your text here");
txtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use number of textviews at run time, You can try using **`GridView`** as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

And Gridview **`item as TextView`**

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/text"
  />
```

You can perform action in **`onItemClickListener()`** //based on the position or textview text, choose action using `switch case` or something else.

```
   GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
   gridView.setAdapter(yourCustomAdapterObject);
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       //here view is your textview
       switch (position) {
           case 0: //action
               break;
           case 1://action
               break;
           ....
           }
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to create TextView programmatically and make Listener for each .
Here is the Code . First remove all textview in layout.

```
TextView tv[] = new TextView[subCategory.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < subCategory.length; i++) {
            tv[i] = new TextView(this);
            tv[i].setText(subCategory[i]);
            tv[i].setId(i);
            layout5.addView(tv[i]); 
            tv[i].setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);
        }
```

And For Listner

```
OnClickListener onclicklistener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == tv[0]){
            //do whatever you want....
        }
    }
};
```